# C global pointer value changes after irrelevant function call

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I run the following code

```
int *pointer;

void fun1() {
    int i;
    pointer = &i;
    *pointer = 11;
}

void fun2() {
    printf("\nFun 2: Hello World\n");
}

int main() {
    pointer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pointer = 0;
    fun1();
    printf("%d\n",*pointer);
    fun2();
    printf("%d\n",*pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
11

Fun 2: Hello World
20
```

I would expect it to be 11 instead of 20. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You are taking a pointer to a local variable. `i` get's invalid/random after your function returns. Possible duplicate to [Why does gcc throw a warning when returning a pointer to a local variable and not when returning a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184315/why-does-gcc-throw-a-warning-when-returning-a-pointer-to-a-local-variable-and-no) and [returning a local variable from function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the pointer to local variable `i`'s address in `fun1` and it stays that way after `fun1` returns. That address is on the stack and later is overwritten with a new value during your call to `fun2` and its `printf` call.

Answer (score 1):

This an example of undefined behavior. When `fun1` is called, `pointer` is pointing to an automatic local variable in `fun1`. Once `fun1` completed its execution that variable no longer exist. Now the statement

```
printf("%d\n",*pointer);
```

invoke undefined behavior.
There is also memory leak in your program.

Comment: Then how the first print gives 11 ? fun1 has ended at this point as well, shouldn't it be undefined behavior as well?

Comment: *Then how the first print gives 11 ?*: Compiler is joking!

Comment: Isn't it what Wormbo says?

Comment: @illeg; Well its UB and anything could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here in `fun1()`

```
pointer = &i;
```

you assign the global pointer to point to a temporary variable that no longer exists when `fun1()` exits. Therefore when you call `printf` with `*pointer` you are accessing invalid memory.

This is undefined behaviour and trying to understand the content of the invalid memory region afterwards is not worthwile.